EXCEL return multiple columns of data combined from several sheets in single workbook
I have a formula which uses VSTACK to combine similar data from several sheets in Column A, and a separate VSTACK that combines the data in Column B. I am trying to return both of these columns side-by-side in a new sheet using a single formula. I feel like the solution must be simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Here is the formula I am using: =LET(a,VSTACK(Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet2!A1:A230,Sheet3!A1:A103, b,VSTACK(Sheet1!A1:A100,Sheet2!A1:A230,Sheet3!A1:A103), FILTER(a,a <>""))
There are some blank rows here and there, which is why I used the filter function. I was hoping to return the two VSTACK arrays side by side. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

HSTACK is a horizontal VSTACK.

Thank you for the help, I was having a bit of trouble figuring out how to combine VSTACK and HSTACK, but looks like I was overthinking the issue. Thanks!

It's not quite clear what you want to do and you have not provided any examples of your inputs and outputs (How do I ask a good question?) but I'm guessing you probably need to add HSTACK to your formula:
=LET(
    a, VSTACK(Sheet1!A1:A100, Sheet2!A1:A230, Sheet3!A1:A103),
    b, VSTACK(Sheet1!B1:B100, Sheet2!B1:B230, Sheet3!B1:B103),
    filtered_a, FILTER(a, a <> ""),
    filtered_b, FILTER(b, b <> ""),
    HSTACK(filtered_a, filtered_b)
)


This worked great! Sorry for the lack of an example, I wasn't sure how to format it to show the arrays in different sheets. Thanks again!
